# Script waiting for files uses 100% CPU in while loop

Tags: python, performance, while-loop, sleep, cpu-usage

I have a script which uses 100% of a single core in a wait-loop. The script should process files that appear in a preset directory. Thus it waits until files show up, and then it processes them. It looks roughly like this:

```
slept = 0
while True:
    if len(glob.glob(src_diretory+suffix)) > 0:
        slept=0
        # cast black magic spells on files ending in suffix, located in src_directory
    else:
        print("Slept "+str(slept)+" times.."
        slept+=1
        sleep.sleep(1)
```

Does in this case the rather frequent `len(glob.glob(src_diretory+suffix))` cause such high CPU usage?

Comment: Are you sure that `else` really works? Do you remove / rename the files from `src_diretory+suffix` directory?

Comment: `else` really works, tested this with `print("something")`, and I just checked the `sleep` is even 1s not 0.1s. And yes, if files are found they are moved, processed then deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first tool to turn to with this sort of issue is a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html), which will tell you where time is spent in detail.

You don't need to test for length greater than zero; a list is true if it has entries, false otherwise. Additionally, you should probably use your entries as they were read. These are however cosmetic changes, so my best guess is that the glob itself takes a long time; are there perhaps a lot of files not matching the pattern in the same directory?

I would suggest a slightly different structure:

```
while True:
    filenames = glob.glob(src_diretory+suffix)
    for filename in filenames:
        pass  # Process file here, including moving it away
    if not filenames:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Ideally you would use an OS-side monitor for changes, such as inotify, kqueue, FSEvents or ReadDirectoryChanges, rather than polling. You might want to try programs that do this specific waiting, such as incron and entr.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop will try to hog as mutch cpu as possible, compare:

```
while True:
    pass

while True:
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I can't test this on the machine the script is running. Your example is a classic for 100% CPU usage, I'm aware of that, but I use a `sleep(0.1)` which is somewhat *long* for a CPU (Quad Core) so I assume the CPU usage results from the `len(glob.glob(src_diretory+suffix))`

Comment: len(glob.glob(src_diretory+suffix)) > 0 goes rather quick I supose and is True most of the times?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the OS(*), you could find low-level functions that allow a program to be warned of the creation of a new file in a directory without doing an active loop. Unfortunately it is non portable, and probably not directly available from Python.

If you are building a high performance system you could look at this, else, you should use a simple spooling algorythm :

- as long as you find files in directory : process them
- as soon as you have no file - sleep a while (common value between 0.1 and 2 seconds) before iterating

(*) exists at least on Windows and recent Linux kernels